# Parse <meta> tag with specified attribute and extract another attribute's value

Tags: php, attributes, html-parsing, preg-replace, meta-tags

I'm working on an engine for my website. It's set up to use meta tags that PHP code then handles and creates the page, making it simple to create pages. I know a lot of people may think this is a bad way of processing things, but it's using dynamic paging to load pages. It will essentially load something like `load.php?url=home`, for example. Then load.php constructs the page if it exists on the server, if not we kill the page and result our 404.

The problem is, I'm using `preg_replace()` right now to get the value that is contained in the meta tags. This returns the page's PHP code.

All I want to do is get the result and then make the result a variable. I tried `preg_filter()` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) is meant for extracting certain snippets. Show your tried code, input sample and expected output.

Comment: I suggest looking at templates like Smarty rather than swapping and changing the data yourself http://www.smarty.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg-match) and use the `$matches` array.

Comment: `$rowCount = preg_replace("/\<meta name=\"rows\" content=\"(\w+)\" session=\"".$zs."\" \/>/", '$1', $contents);` This is what I have with preg_replace. preg_match boggles my mind

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing valid/parsable HTML, then avoid regex patterns and use a DOM-aware approach.  DOMDocument paired with XPath will reliably extract the desire attribute value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FHhuC))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<meta name="rows" content="barry" session="fooey" />
HTML;
$zs = 'fooey';

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo (new DOMXPath($dom))->evaluate('string(//meta[@session="' . $zs. '"]/@content)');
// barry
```